# Access ADSL modem's web interface connected to a router

Tags: networking, router, modem

I have 3COM 3CRWER100-70 router and Aztech ADSL2+ ETHERNET BRIDGE ROUTER DSL 600E modem connected to it.
My network computers connected to the router and access the internet.

Is it possible to access modem's web interface?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, your wireless router (internal device) will have an address of http://192.168.1.1/ and the cable modem or DSL modem could have an address of http://192.168.100.1/

I'm assuming your network configuration is like this

ISP -> Modem -> Router -> Computer

Of course, this depends on your modem manufacturer and ISP settings.

Comment: I've also seen http://192.168.0.254, http://192.168.1.254.

Comment: my router is indeed 192.168.1.1 , but modem (when connected directly to pc) is 10.0.0.138.
The modem is not connected into router's one of 4 lan sockets, it's connected to a DSL socket.

Comment: In my experience, a modem will have an internal (public) IP address, and a private address. An address of 10.0.0.138 is indeed a private address, but it's odd. You should be able to access that IP address even if the modem is plugged into the router

Answer (score -1):

Actually your router can also be thought of as a computer through which all the data passes. It is your network gateway.

To know what is the address of the Router, you need to follow these steps
Find out the IP address of your computer, let us say it is 192.168.0.3
Next find out the subnet mask, it can be 255.255.255.0
Another field would be gateway address which is also shown below these two in Windows XP for sure. On Linux it depends on the UI you using.

Now you need to find the network address, you need to do a bitwise AND on your computer's IP address and network mask, doing so, you would get the network address which is 192.168.0.0 in my case. The gateway address is 192.168.0.1 which is the IP address of my router.

As per the convention the first and last address in a subnet is reserved. The first address (192.168.0.0 in my case) is the network's address. The last address (192.168.0.255) is the broadcast address of the subnet.

The router has the address http://192.168.0.1. Now you need to connect to type this in the address bar. Many routers keep the advanced options in a different page which. In my and many routers it is http://192.168.0.1/main.html